# javascript -how to launch an event from a web component, from outside it

Tags: javascript, web-component

I need a solution with this, I am trying to fire an event from within a web-component with the handleEvent, but I am not able:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        paintElement2(this);
    }

    handleEvent(event) {
        console.log(event.type); // doesn't work
    }
}

customElement.define("my-element", MyElement);

function paintElement2(elementWhoCall) {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.textContent = "click me and launch event inside the caller";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        elementWhoCall.dispatchEvent(new Event("myevent"));
    });
}
```

Thx!

Comment: try to first add the event listener and only then append it to your document

Comment: This will only work if ``<my-element>`` is **nested** inside the A tag, because the listener is on the A tag. And nowhere is ``handleEvent`` called. https://javascript.info/events is a good starting place to learn

Comment: @liad thx for comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

The best in my opinion:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.addEventListener("myevent", this)
        paintElement2(this);
    }

    handleEvent(event) {
        console.log(event.type); 
    }
}

customElement.define("my-element", MyElement);

function paintElement2(elementWhoCall) {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.textContent = "click me and launch event inside the caller";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        elementWhoCall.dispatchEvent(new Event("myevent"));
    });
}
```

The second option:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        paintElement2(this);
    }

    handleEvent(event) {
        console.log(event.type); // doesn't work
    }
}

customElement.define("my-element", MyElement);

function paintElement2(elementWhoCall) {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.textContent = "click me and launch event inside the caller";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        elementWhoCall.handleEvent(new Event("myevent"));
    });
}
```